# Error : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot, jpa

I am getting error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration while running a spring code from spring tool suite

I have already googled and checked stackoverflow for the resolution ,but no luck .

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.thoughtworkstest</groupId>
<artifactId>supermarket</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>supermarket</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.156</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependencies for SQLite -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.25.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.kemitix</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is app-context.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder 
  location="classpath:META-INF/spring/hibernate.properties"/>

 <bean id="dataSource" 
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
  <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
  <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
  <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="sessionFactory" 
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="annotatedClasses" value="com.test.market.model.ItemDetails" />
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>


</beans>
```

Comment: Instead of using XML configuration you can mention your config in application.properties or yml file.

Comment: Looking at the [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/3.0.6.RELEASE), Spring ORM 3.0.6 was developed against Hibernate Entity Manager 3.4.0.GA. Does it work if you downgrade the Hibernate dependency to that version?

Comment: As a side note, I'm pretty sure `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` already depends on all that is necessary to use Spring Data JPA with Hibernate in your project. You don't need the explicit dependencies on neither `spring-orm` nor `hibernate-entitymanager`

Comment: You are pulling hibernate 5.x as a transitive dependency, and replace only 2 modules with 3.6 version. Even worse: you replace only one, as `hibernate-entitymanager` was deprecated and renamed to `hibernate-core`.

Comment: Remofve the `hibernate-entitymanager` dependency, that is already included in the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency, also ditch the `spring-orm` dependency as that is also included in that dependency, next to that you are using an ancient version of it with Spring 5.x that is never going to work. Hibernate 3 isn't supported anymore in Spring 5 and up so you will need to use Hibernate 5 (which is automaticalluy included).

Answer (score 3):

You are using Spring Boot 2.1.3 which depends on Spring 5.1. The Spring 5.x line works only with Hibernate 5.x, support for earlier versions has been dropped.

The `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency already includes the `hibernate-entitymanager` dependency in a version that works with the other dependencies.

Annother is is that you are mixing jars/modules from different versions of Spring you are mixing 5.1.x and 3.0.6, that is always trouble as those are quite incompatible. Furthermore that dependency is also included in the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

So in short, you dependencies are a bit of mess.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
    <!-- Dependencies for SQLite -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.25.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.kemitix</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**NOTE:** Spring Boot can also manage the H2 version, hence you can remove the `version` tag from that.

You are using XML, however I would strongly suggest to ditch that and use JPA instead. With the current state of JPA there is no really a need to use plain Hibernate anymore. And if you really must, you can use `EntityManager.unwrap(Session.class)` to obtain the underlying session.

The added advantage is that you can now use the auto-configuration for JPA from Spring Boot. The properties in your `hibernate.properties` should go in the `application.properties` under the correct names.

```
spring.datasource.url= # your jdbc.url value
spring.datasource.username = # your jdbc.username value
spring.datasource.password = # your jdbc.password value

spring.jpa.database-platform = # your hibernate.dialect value
spring.jpa.show-sql = # your hibernate.show_sql value
```

**NOTE:** You don't need to specify the `driver-classname` property as Spring Boot and JDBC will detect that based on the given `jdbc-url`.

**TIP:** Make sure that your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in the `com.test.market` package, as recommended by the Spring Boot team, so it will detect all your classes, including your `@Entity` annotated classes.

Your code, you might need to change to use `EntityManager` instead of `SessionFactory` and `Session` but that should be a minor change.

Comment: Thanks M.Deinum for the detailed answer . I will try this out and update you.

Answer (score 1):

Like @crizzis said try removing all other dependencies and provide only the following :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Spring starter data jpa already includes all the necessary dependencies like hibernate-core,hibernate-commons-annotations,javax.persistence-api,spring jdbc,h2 etc. So try removing all other data related dependencies from your pom and let springboot handle all such dependencies through it's starter.When you explicitly provide the version and dependency it will override the started dependency and may cause incompatible version issues if you are not careful.

Comment: Thanks Anantha . I will try out the solution and update you .